# Windows Authentication and web.config renaimg

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We are facing a strange issue with ASP.net Application using Windows Authentication and required some expert advice for resolution. Below is the detail scenario

1- Application-1: deployed on IIS on its own App.pool, Call the default page and provided the User ID and Password on IIS windows login screen. It successfully logged in=>No Issues.

2- Application-2: Create a new virtual directory on Same IIS and copy the web content of Application-1. Call default page and provided the User ID and Password on IIS windows login screen, It fails and Keep prompting Login screen

3- Rename the web.config in Application 2 to anything. e.g web123.config.

4- Call the Default Page of Application 2. It shows error which is obvious as IIS unable to find the web.config.

5- Reverse the name of web config from web123.config to web.config in Application 2.

6- Now call the application 2 again as per step 4, and it works.

It seems the IIS is overwriting some thing once we call the application with no web config as in step-4. But What and why it is not working at Step 2, where as technically we did not change any thing in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why renaming the web.config makes this work for you, but I have had this issue with duplicate websites on the same server having conflicting cookies. Without renaming the web.config can you do this and change the cookie name and see if anything changes?